# Enable TCP connection for SQL Server for specific users only

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Can I enable TCP connection in SQL server 2008 R2 to only specific users, or at the other side, can I prevent some users from connecting to SQL Server remotely using TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER remote_connection_limit_trigger
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @result XML
SET @result = EVENTDATA()
DECLARE @spid NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @spid = @result.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)')

DECLARE @connectionType NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @connectionType = net_transport FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE  session_id = @spid


IF @connectionType = 'TCP' AND ORIGINAL_LOGIN() <> 'temp_remote_user'
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Logon Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598.aspx) feature to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks very much, it appears to be the solution, but how to know the connection type (Shared memory, named pipes, or TCP) inside this Logon Triggers

Comment: In the logon trigger code obtain `spid` value from EVENTDATA, then check sys.dm_exec_connections view and look for `net_transport` column.